# issue with Mongoose assigning JSON to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Thank you in advance for anyone that reads this. I really appreciate any and all help.

so this is my first app personal app. I have setup a DB in Atlas on mongodb.com and I can write to it with out an issue. But when my app tries and pull from my db I can get it to print to console. But I am able to assign the data to any variable to use anywhere else in my my app.

here is my code that works to print to the console. But not sure what setup or package I am missing so i can store it as a local variable. I am using a callback function to return the api call and the console print out works. just dont know what to do next

```js
function getTerms() {
    
    let allTerms = []
    termAdd.find({}, '_id', (err, term) => {
            
            term.map((term) => {
                allTerms.push(term)
                // if I understand Push() correctly this should store my output to allTerms.
            });

            //this works to print out to console in JSON.
            console.log(allTerms, 'getTerms')
            return allTerms;
            
        });
    };
    
    
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        //callback function to return the console from the function
        getTerms()

       // when i do a let foo = getTerms() it will return undefined
       //so I am really dont understand how to assign the return from 
      //the function to a variable. 


        //How do I assign this console output to variable to use for output

        console.log('200 statusCode')
    };

        //Random Number Generator
        let ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        console.log('random number = ',ranNum);

        res.render('fs', {
            flashCard : 'Test Card',
            items: ranNum
        });
    
});
```

I have the full code on GitHub if that would help I can link to this project.

Should I be using a delay in anyway. I was given a suggestion. But I did not understand what I was reading.

Comment: i am trying to understand what you want to store; is it the string '200 statusCode'? sorry

Comment: so I am trying to store the return from getTerms Function.

but when i assign "let foo = getTerms()" it returns and unified in the console. So where is the data

Comment: i believe that before anything, you should separate your functions; there are way too many things happening in `getTerms()`. if I'm not mistaken, are you calling `getTerms()` again inside of it?

Comment: can you share the rest of the code?

Comment: oh no no no! delete that. don't ever share that link; it contains the URI of your database and your password. as a matter of fact, it's best to not share anything that's in your .env and don't ever push your .env file to Github

Comment: no worries. I set this up this user as just a read-only user. They data is honestly just some AWS key terms I am storing. so no sensitive data is involved. But thank you for the warning.

after this was resolved I was going to remove that user as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, please abstain of pushing your `.env` file to Github or sharing anything in it publicly.

You separated the functionality of getting terms into its own function, which is good:

```js
// Get function for all items in mongodb
function allItems(all) {
    let allTerms = []
    termAdd.find({}, 'term', (err, term) => {
            
            term.map((term) => {
                allTerms.push(term)
            });
            //this works to print out to console.
            console.log(allTerms, 'function allTerms')  
            //Question is how to I get this JSON to save to a VAR or be passed to another function
        });
};
```

First of all I would rename it to `getAllTerms`, since it's what it does. And it seems the `all` parameter is not necessary.

**

Anyway, usually, what you would do is simply return the `allTerms` variable as such:

```js
// Get function for all items in mongodb
function getAllTerms() {
    let allTerms = []
    termAdd.find({}, 'term', (err, term) => {
            
            term.map((term) => {
                allTerms.push(term)
            });
            //this works to print out to console.
            console.log(allTerms, 'function allTerms')  
            //Question is how to I get this JSON to save to a VAR or be passed to another function
        });
    return allTerms
}
```

However, this wouldn't work because since you are making a call to a database, it might take some time for the database to get the terms; in this case, `allTerms` might return an empty array, `[]`.

What you have to do is *wait* for the database to return the terms, push them into the `allTerms` array, and finally return it.

```js
// Get function for all items in mongodb
async function getAllTerms() {
    let allTerms = []
    const fetchedTerms = await termAdd.find({}, 'term')
    fetchedTerms.forEach(fetchedTerm => allTerms.push(fetchedTerm))
    return allTerms
}
```

If you don't know what `async` and `await` are, no worries, [here is a good article explaining the why and when to use them.](https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc#:%7E:text=Async%2FAwait%20is%20a%20fancier,it%20awaits%20resolves%20or%20rejects.)

If you still have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for the help. But I feel like I am getting the same error. Where items show up in the console. But they are not being passed to the screen. on my web page I am getting [object Promise] do I have to do some type of look on or in the function callback to make this information usable?

Comment: @AugustoRodriguez try using `async` and `await` when you call `getAllTerms()` as well

Comment: thank you for the help. I will keep working on this tomorrow. looks like I have to get my head around async and await.

Comment: @AugustoRodriguez no problem, let me know if you have any other issues

Comment: Hey thank you for all the help. I am now able to use these variables as content on my page with handle bars.

Answer (score -1):

Using Async/Await the code above can be optimized as the code below:

`

```
async function getTerms() {
    //using async/await 
    try{
    const terms = await termAdd.find({}, '_id')
    const allTerms = terms.map((term)=>term)
    // return allTerms here
    return allTerms
    }catch(err){
      throw err
    }
 }
```

`

for more insight on Async/Await [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await/) is a good read